# .htaccess 1and1.com Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have just deploy my site to the server `1and1.com` and second level pages is not working.
I have tried:

**Not works**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (ecart|backend|members|member|login)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(ecart|backend|members|member|login)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

**Not works**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**not works**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Not works**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

- This question is possible duplicate of many questions but they all not works for me.
- I am not getting the 404 Error I am getting 500 Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

If it doesn't work try commenting out the `RewriteBase` line:

```
#RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain me this a bit..  its works without commenting the line :)

Comment: I just find that, depending on the host, it sometimes isn't necessary.

Comment: waiting for the delay :)

Comment: Perfect! You've saved my life